# std::move to a function

Tags: c++, std, move

I have this example code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Struct {
public:
   Struct() { std::cout << "0" << std::endl; }
   Struct(Struct&) { std::cout <<"1"<<std::endl;}
   Struct(const Struct&) { std::cout << "2" << std::endl; }
};

class Struct2 {
public:
    Struct s;

    Struct2() {}
    void setMember(const Struct& aux) { s = aux; }
};

int main()
{
    Struct s;
    Struct2 s2;
    s2.setMember(s);
}
// http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dd57e8af23f6db4b
```

**Doubt 1:**

It is printting two 0, because the constructor in the main and the construct of the member of Struct2.

The thing is, I was expecting three 0, because the "setMember" is receiving a copy of 's', right? What is happening then?

**Doubt 2:**

I was thinking in putting this:

```
s2.setMember(std::move(s));
```

As I won't use 's' again, but the setMember does not have '&&' specified, is it ok? Do i have to also do this? :

```
s = std::move(aux);
```

Or with just the main one is enough?

**Doubt 3 :**

```
std::vector<A> vectorA;

int main()
{
    A a;
    // modifies a ...
    vectorA.push_back(std::move(a));
}
```

Is it correct? Am I optimizing anything moving 'a'? It will not be used anymore and I want to keep it in the vector

Thanks

Comment: passing arguments as reference is the exact opposite from passing as value (copy). here, non of your c.tros pass the argument by value.

Comment: If you don't understand the pass-by-reference mechanism, maybe you should read a bit more about basic C++ before diving in move semantics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because the "setMember" is receiving a copy of 's', right?

Well, no. It's receiving a `const&` and copies on assignment operator. Since you haven't overloaded the assignment operator, nothing is printed out.

---

> `s2.setMember(std::move(s));`

This won't solve anything; `std::move` will just cast `s` to rvalue, but inside of the function it's still a `const&`.

---

Rule of thumb: pass-by-value, move out inside:

```
void setMember(Struct aux) { s = std::move(aux); }
```

That way it will "automagically" work; copying lvalues on interface / moving rvalues into the parameter value, and then moving the parameter value into the actual object member.

Of course to make optimal use of that machinery, you need an rvalue passed there, so...

```
Struct s;
Struct2 s2;
s2.setMember(std::move(s));
```

Or perhaps...

```
s2.setMember(Struct());
```

That being said, your old code won't break.

---

As for the third example, yes, this is OK, altough I'd *probably* either

- move the change to `a` to another function and `push_back(function())`
- move the changes to `a` to `A`s constructor and use `emplace_back`

Comment: So at the end which is the most efficient way? I just want to assign this 's' to the member of s2. s2.setMember(std::move(s)) then?

Comment: @user3468999 Elaborate on "efficient". If you want to avoid copies, don't write statements that cause copies, I think it's pretty simple. The key point to understand is that taking a value doesn't necessarily copy. So what I suggested (taking a value) will be fine.

Comment: Also I updated the post with a third doubt, if you could check it out please... :)